# How to use a directory of filenames as arguments in a linux shell command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to run the following command in linux, `python3 pythonScript.py filename1 filename2 filename3 filename4 filenameN.....`

If I wanted to run the filenames as a list I would do `python3 pythonScript.py $(< filenamelist.txt)` where filename list.txt contains filename1 filename2 filename3 filename4 filenameN.... in each line.

Is there a way I can run this command without generating the list and just feed the directory of filenames directly into the command?

Comment: You need to specify whether the filenames must remain in the order of `filename1 filename2 filename3 filename4, ... filenameN` or not as, e.g., `filename10` will sort before `filename2` using globbing, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
find somefolder -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 python3 pythonScript.py
```

Comment: hi, im getting an error because the whole directory is being parsed, ~/somedir/subdir when I used it after find, is there a way to make only the filenames inside the subdir to be parsed?

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` means that it will output only the names within the folder you are setting right before that, and will not go recursively within each folder.. Please give exact example of your folder structure, and what your goal is, which files you want and you do not want to get, so we find a solution..

Comment: okay, I only need the filenames in the subdir folder, I run ```find ~/Documents/testing/1FilesMaker/servernames/ -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 echo ```, the servernames folder has the filenames which I require, but this command is printing the whole directory ```/Users/username/Documents/testing/1FilesMaker/servernames/servername1``` I only need ```servername1```. can that be done?

Comment: `find ~/Documents/testing/1FilesMaker/servernames/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \;|xargs -0 echo`

Comment: it prints the name of the folder first as well, is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: can I just use ```ls ~/Documents/testing/1FilesMaker/servernames/  |xargs -0 echo``` ? , but I want them all to appear in 1 line.

Comment: `ls /tmp/|xargs echo`

Answer (score 1):

Try brace expansion.

```sh
python3 pythonscript.y filename{1..10}
```

- If you need to set the `N` limit to a variable, then you need a loop, because brace expansion happens before variable does in bash.

Comment: Worth a comment if the OP is interested in ALL files in the folder prefixed with `filename`, then just `filename*`.

Comment: The `*` glob might sort it differently depending on the `locale` and if you have, say `filename.txt` that will be included as well, just saying :-)

Comment: Very true, it's hard to know the exact requirements when little is given.

Comment: how would the command look like with filename* , there is no file extension at the end.

Comment: Exactly what you have.

Comment: so ```python3 pythonScript.py ~/somedir/somedir/filename*``` ?